# Unity configuration does not apply when I use ccsm

Tags: unity, 11.10, compiz

when I configure unity via CompizConfig Settings Manager or dconf, the settings can be seen like they applied but unity doesn't care

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this problem, try logging out and back in and see if the settings take.

Answer (score 0):

If a log out/in still doesn't show changes then maybe you are using unity-2d instead of unity(3d)
There are many ways to tell, to save time & typing just run this in a terminal, will be obvious

ps aux |grep unity